# MS Access Report showing the id of the combobox and not the bound name column

Tags: ms-access, reporting

The company I work for have an access database that is linked to a sql server table. The database is on a shared network location so it is used by lots of people in the company (with the annoying problem that only one person can use it at a time).
There are several forms that are used as a front end for the data and on one particular form there are combo boxes that are linked to other tables. 
When a report is generated on the form the ID of the combobox is on the form (a GUID) and not the bound item of the combobox.

How can I get the bound items to appear on the form itself? The solution needs to be easy to do or something i can produce that can be regenerated as it's used by non technical people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the database usable by many, simply give each user a copy of the front-end.

Forms should almost never be used for reports, the best thing to do is to build a query (the query design window will help) that references each of the relevant tables, for example, if the combobox contained a reference to person type and you might build a query like this for your report:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.SName, a.MainAddress, c.PersonType 
FROM Addresses a
INNER JOIN PersonTypes c     ''Or LEFT JOIN if data is missing
ON a.PersonTypeKey = c.PersonTypeKey
```

If this is not possible, perhaps you could explain in more detail exactly how the report is generated from the form.

Comment: At the minute all they are doing is clicking "Create Report" on the form and deleting the columns they don't want. Ill give your idea a go and come back. Thanks for your speedy reply!

Comment: Forms are not reports. Reports are reports.